# ERROR While running sfdx force:source:deploy command

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, package.xml, source

I am getting an error while running:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u Sandbox -x pathToPackage.xml
```

My deployments were just fine but after I did a sfdx force retrieve from a sandbox then I started to get this error below.

Any ideas on how to fix?

```
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
{ Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\lazystream\lib\lazystream.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at LazyLoader.loadIfNeeded (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:63:19)
    at Object.get (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\@salesforce\lazy-require\lib\LazyLoader.js:219:28)
    at Proxy.utils.lazyReadStream (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:78:25)
    at Archiver._updateQueueTaskWithStats (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:438:24)
    at Archiver._append (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:105:17)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:663:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver\lib\core.js:644:15
    at next (c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:131:16)
    at c:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules\archiver-utils\index.js:148:13
  errno: -4066,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path:
   'c:\\Program Files\\Salesforce CLI\\client\\node_modules\\lazystream\\lib\\lazystream.js' }
```

Comment: Does restarting your computer fix the problem? It sounds like there might be some kind of leak in whatever shell/IDE you're using, which a restart would at least resolve temporarily. We'll need to do more research to see if it's a DX problem or not. Also, how many files do you have in the deploy folder?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, I did restart my pc it did not help. So, I tried running the same command on the same package.xml except this time I commented out every single meta data in the package.xml except for one and that deployment went through. But, if I deploy the package.xml with all the metadata then its giving me issues.

Comment: This seems to be a common node error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files It might have to do with how sfdx reads files to deploy. Maybe one of your metadata folders has many components and sfdx can't handle it because of what that post states.

Comment: @GlenDeMarcos I think you are correct. The issue happened when I did a source retrieve from my sandbox with a bunch of metadata. I think there was either too much metadata retrieved or there were some that just won't corporate with SFDX.

Comment: I also encounter this error when I try to Authorize my org. The problem is I just downloaded a bunch of extensions. What worked for me is I close, refresh and open VSCode again.